# Excel autofill between worksheets

Tags: excel

I have an excel document with ~300 similar worksheets and 1 worksheet with a list of names. Each of these 300 worksheets has a specific cell where I need to fill a name from the list. The list and the sheets are in the same order (for example sheet1 needs a name from List!C1, sheet2 from List!C2 etc). I looked into VLOOKUP, but there isn't any reference data I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for similar task you need use VBA Macros like this:

```
Sub DataFromList()

Dim nameSht As String: nameSht = "List"
Dim shtList As Worksheet
Set shtList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(nameSht)

Dim columnWithData As String: columnWithData = "C"
Dim n%: n = 0 ' start from 1 row (0 + 1)

' specific cell where you need to fill a name from the list
Dim addressForData As String: addressForData = "B2"

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> nameSht Then
        n = n + 1
        sht.Range(addressForData).Formula = "=" & nameSht & "!" & columnWithData & n
    End If
Next sht
End Sub
```

of course, it possible only if address of "specific cell" same in all sheet

Comment: Your code is solid and maintainable and usually best (assuming reliable expected iterator order which i _think_ is true). However I would like to note that contrary to your first sentence hypothesis, assuming consistent sheet naming, VBA is not required. You could select all sheets then deselect List and input an INDIRECT formula stripping n from the sheet name.

Comment: Naturally, the code can give sequence, which will not work (it will happen, if the sheets are moved or renamed, and issued the sequence will be different from the sorting by name). But we can always first sort array of sheet`s names, and then add formulas into sheets. It is not difficult, but it seemed to me unnecessary for a first example of a possible solution.